# Is it possible to create a table with a hh:mm time column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to create a table column that has a ***hh:mm*** format. How do I do that?

I've tried it with ***time(0)*** but that also gives me the seconds.

```
CREATE TABLE courseTimes (
  startingTime time(0),
  endingTime time(0)
);
```

I want the entries to look like

> startingTime 19:25
>
> endingTime 20:10

for example.

Comment: It will store the time in it's native format. When you retrieve the time, that's when you have it format it in whatever way you like.

Comment: Understood, how do I format it thought? Could you give me a SELECT example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the time and format it like this.

```
Select
 TIME_FORMAT(startingTime),'%H:%i' ),
 TIME_FORMAT(endingTime),'%H:%i' )
```